# OpenCL, my GPU it's not capable?

Tags: c, opencl, gpu

I have an old computer, then I don't know if I can execute OpenCL codes on my PC; I've checked my GPU and I get this output:
[image]

When I execute OpenCL code, I get this error:

[image]

Finally, if I run clinfo, i get this:

[image]

I really don't know..It's a problem of libraries?Or my GPU cannot execute OpenCL codes?

Comment: You have an integrated GPU. Add a powerful dedicated card

Comment: But with my integrated GPU I can't?The problem is that I'm not using a Desktop PC but a laptotp

Comment: Which CPU do you have? Should be able to run OpenCL if it's new enough.

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T5870  @ 2.00GHz, it's a little old..

Answer (score 1):

Your GPU predates OpenCL. Beignet supports Ivybridge and later (https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Beignet/#supportedtargets).

Your CPU also predates OpenCL. Intel's first release of their CPU-only OpenCL driver requires SSE4.1, but your CPU only has SSE3. If you really really need to get OpenCL to work on this machine, you may be able to install an old version (2.8) of the AMD OpenCL CPU driver if you can find it. Quote from http://boinc.berkeley.edu/wiki/OpenclCpu:

> - Intel's OpenCL support requires the SSE4.1 CPU feature (BOINC's event log shows you the list of your CPU's features).
> - If your host does not have SSE4.1 support, then you can install the AMD APP SDK 2.8 and it will install the AMD OpenCL CPU driver. Note that the AMD APP SDK v2.9 will NOT install it. You have to use 2.8 or earlier as they now bundle the OpenCL driver with the video driver instead of with the APP SDK. As AMD only keeps the last several versions on their archive page, you may want to grab both the 32 and 64 bit version of the v2.8 APP SDK now and keep them in a safe place.

Or maybe POCL or FreeOCL might cover you for the CPU.